# Javascript Vanilla - Double Click event handler on inputs / GetElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, double-click, getelementsbytagname

**Problem:** Can't assign a double-click event handler to my generated inputs; is this feasible using the `getElementsByTagName`?

Thanks for any help

Here is the code:

---

**Generated inputs**

```
function list_tasks() {
    let container = document.getElementById("todo");
    container.innerHTML = ""

    if (task_array.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < task_array.length; i++) {
            let input = document.createElement("input");
            input.value = task_array[i];
            input.classList.add("record");
            input.disabled = true;
            container.appendChild(input);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Attaching the event**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("record").addEventListener("dblclick", editTask);
```

---

**And the console.log is never called**

```
function editTask(e){
   console.log("double click")
}
```

---

**Update**
Trying to loop across the array, but still, no double click event is fired

```
let record = document.getElementsByClassName("record");
for(var i = 0; i <= record.length; i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("record")[i].addEventListener("dblclick", editTask);
}
```

Comment: Not exactly related to your question but the command : if (task_array.length > 0)  is redundant . Your next line of code makes sure that the loop is not executed in the length of the tasks array is 0

Comment: Added to what @ShaiAharoni wrote, you are also doing the `document.getElementsByClassName("record")` lookup twice which is not a good practice, in case you have a large document - each such call needs to iterate over the entire tree.

Comment: The issue was only related to trying to assign a double click event to a disabled input. I'll have to find another way.

Comment: A "fancy" way might be hiding the input and replacing it with some inline-block element that might look like an input, but it's really just a div/span with text inside, instead of really disabling the input.

Comment: Thanks @Nomaed , will investigate that :)

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a nodes list i.e. an array. To access the element you need to get the value form the array.

Try this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("record")[0].addEventListener("dblclick", editTask);
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so I updated the way I'm setting the event listener, but still no event is triggered, would you have a few secs to check ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this doesn't work is because you are marking the inputs as disabled. Disabled inputs don't react to some events, and looks like double-click is one of them.

Also, as @Royson wrote, `getElementsByClassName()` returns a list of multiple elements. If you want to add an event listener to all of them you have 2 options:

The best one IMO, if possible, is to attach it while creating the elements in `list_tasks()` function:

```
let input = document.createElement("input");
input.value = task_array[i];
input.classList.add("record");
input.disabled = true;
input.addEventListener("dblclick", editTask); // <--- here
container.appendChild(input);
```

If this is not possible to due scopes being inaccessible, you just loop over the result of `getElementsByClassName()`:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("record")).forEach(el => el.addEventListener("dblclick", editTask));
```

---

*Edit:* The spec says that "click" events should be disabled on a disabled input. Event though double-click isn't specified directly, my guess is that it's implied by it being a click too, or it requires click to be enabled so it can catch two fast ones.
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls%3A-the-disabled-attribute

Answer (score -1):

The way to do it is to create items as list items and then make contentEditable on the list items on double click B-)